# Is there anything like java servlet in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am from Java background just started with asp.net mvc. I am wondering is there anything in ASP.NET that corresponds to servlet and anything matching request and response object.

Any link will be appreciated.

Regards,

Deepak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478987.aspx

> there are two ways to replace servlet
>   functionality in ASP.NET: using a
>   codebehind for an ASP.NET page with no
>   HTML, or creating an HttpHandler.